# Delete All Record and Create new Records in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my Controller i have open action.this action should remove all record of model and then send ajax request and get new models and replace model. my ember data adapter is [LSA](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter)

```
OlapApp.OpenController = Ember.Controller.extend({
needs: ['application'],
actions: {
    open: function() {
        var self = this;
        var xhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'http://localhost:9095/service.asmx/getModel',
            data: '{}',
            success: function(response) {
                //Success Empty AxisModel;
                var data = JSON.parse(response.d);
                self.store.findAll('axisModel').then(function(items) {
                    console.log('try to delete');
                    items.forEach(function(item) {
                        item.deleteRecord();
                        item.save();
                    });
                });

                setTimeout(function() {
                    //Fill Axis Model
                    _.each(data.axisModel, function(v, i) {
                        var record = self.store.createRecord('axisModel', {
                            id: v["id"],
                            uniqueName: v["uniqueName"],
                            name: v["name"],
                            hierarchyUniqueName: v.hierarchyUniqueName,
                            type: v["type"],
                            isMeasure: v.isMeasure,
                            orderId: v.orderId,
                            isActive: v.isActive,
                            isAll: v.isAll,
                            sort: v.sort
                        });
                        record.save();
                    });
                    self.get('controllers.application').send('showNotification',     'Open', 'success');

                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    }
}
});
```

but when i try to create a new models i get this error :

```
Assertion failed: The id a12 has already been used with another record of type OlapApp.AxisModel. 
Assertion failed: The id a13 has already been used with another record of type OlapApp.AxisModel.
```

---

**SOLUTION**

finally i find the solution.for fix this problem just wrap deleteRecord() in Ember.run.once like this :

```
self.store.findAll('axisModel').then(function(items) {
                    items.forEach(function(item){
                          Ember.run.once(function(){
                           item.deleteRecord();
                         item.save();
                         });
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **deleting records** there are problems using **forEach** because the result of a find to the store is a live array. You can see this discussion in GitHub https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/772. You can make use of toArray() in order to make a static copy of the live array)

```
self.store.findAll('axisModel').then(
    function(items) {
            items.toArray().forEach(function(item){
                item.deleteRecord();
                item.save();
            });
        });
```